# What is a regular expression for a WPA-bssid

Tags: regex, networking, format, wpa, bssid

is this format ?

```
wpa-bssid 00:1a:2b:3c:4d:5e
```

or

```
wpa-bssid 00:12:26:36:48:58
```

can I use this regex?

```
^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$
```

any help woulb be appreciated

Comment: What result do you want to get from the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its OK and more precise you can use :

```
([0-9A-F]{2}([:-]|$)){6}
```

Comment: However, you should be aware that some systems might not return leading zeroes. For example, iOS 13 returned "8:96:d7:...", and the regex failed.